# How to insert a folder into .tar file in MATLAB by using UNIX commands?

Tags: matlab, unix

I have many folder like `data_1,data_2, data_3` etc, that will be generated during program running. I want to copy these folders into `.tar` file named  `full_data.tar` in a specified folder.

How can I insert folders named `data_1,data_2, data_3` etc into `full_data.tar` in MATLAB by using UNIX commands?

Comment: You can run shell commands from Matlab command line by prepending the command with `!`. See documentation [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/run-external-commands-scripts-and-programs.html). So assuming you are on a *nix system, does this work - `!tar -cvf full_tar.tar data_1 data_2 data_3`?

Answer (score 1):

As @kedarps already proposed I would also use the command line. The matlab command to execute command line arguments is:

```
status = system(command)
```

It is documented under this link:

[system documentation](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html)

So if I take the unixcommand from @kedarps this should work:

```
system('tar -cvf full_tar.tar data_1 data_2 data_3')
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Actually, the `!` suggested by kedarps is short-hand for `system`, and shouldn’t be in the string passed to `system`.  Thus it’s either `system('tar...')` or `!tar...`.

Comment: Nice :) I did not know that. Thank you Cris. I edited my response